# DataTable columns data with Twig

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, twig

My DataTable requests data from columns in my database, I am now interested in adding data that is calculated through a Twig function.

What is the correct way to insert a Twig line so that it results in a DataTable?

```
   columns: [ 
  { data: 'Cars' },
  { data: 'Boats' },
  { data: 'Nightclubs'},
  { data: '{{ blabla.randomfunction }}' },
 ],
```

Comment: The JavaScript code is in the Twig template, right, not in a separate document? (Just making sure)

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: It looks like that should work. (It does work in a basic test I created.) If it's not working, can you edit your question to make more of a [mcve]? It's missing some context that might show what's wrong with it. But just in general, you should be able to use Twig syntax inside your script just like you can anywhere else in the template.

Comment: How do you set it up in the DefaultController?